# How to download files through active ssh session in Coursera Lab?

Tags: shell

[image]

Sometimes you need to archive and download your exercise code from Qwiklabs in Coursera.
What is the easy and best way to do this using shell command in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using following utilizing scp command.
suppose that you want to connect to the user@ip given by the https://googlecoursera.qwiklabs.com/.

General syntax:

```
you@local_machine:scp -i *.pem  user@ip:/dir/file.zip  ./current_directory
```

*.pem file would be available in https://googlecoursera.qwiklabs.com/ for download after starting your Lab.

Please share your proposed solution as well.